# Problema al balancear carga de contenedores de Docker con Nginx

Tags: nodejs, docker, nginx

Tengo un server con 4vCPU y 8GB de RAM hosteando una API REST en Node. Quería utilizar de una forma mas eficiente los CPU's por lo que aproveche que estoy probando Docker y cree una imagen de Node con mi API e inicie 4 contenedores. Configure mi server Nginx para que balance la carga entre esos cuatro contenedores. El problema es que no mejoro el rendimiento, es mas, empeoro un poco.

**Configuracion Nginx:**

```
upstream app{
        server 192.168.1.12:3000;
        server 192.168.1.12:3001;
        server 192.168.1.12:3002;
        server 192.168.1.12:3003;
}

server{
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

**Inicio de los contenedores:**

```
docker run -dit --name node -p 3000:3000 node-api:0.4
```

> PD: probé utilizar el modulo cluster de node y se nota una mejora en el rendimiento. Los server que tengo dentro de los containers no utilizan este modulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo armarte un archivo **docker-compose.yml**, donde tengas el manifiesto para correr tu container de node, y además agregarle un container nginx que en su puerto 80 le este apuntando a tu container de node (como lo estas haciendo ahora). Lo correcto para balancear estos containers es, hacer un [deploy con docker-swarm](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/swarm-deploy/), el cual esta preparado para ejecutar los container en entornos productivos, etc. A tu archivo **docker-compose.yml** de siempre le podes agregar una nueva clave deploy, donde le podes decir cuantas replicas de este container queres corriendo. Ejemplo:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    image: nodejs
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    deploy:
      replicas: 4

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Deployas con el siguiente comando

```
docker stack deploy -c bb-stack.yaml demo
```

Y ya deberias tener 4 contenedores correctamente balanceados.